# Remove Cash On Delivery Instructions From WooCommerce Emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

Here is what my email looks like currently:
[image]

I have spent some time trying to remove this: 
**`'Pay wish cash upon arriving to destination.'`**

But cannot make it go away without removing other stuff.

Please help if you can.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

— Update 1 —

In backend, if you go to WooCommerce > settings > Checkout > Cash on Delivery (tab), you will see:

[image]

> You will be able to remove "Pay wish cash upon arriving to destination." instructions message, or to replace it with something more convenient.

---

You could try to use the WordPress [**`gettext()`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQH54.jpg) function that will remove your text this way:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'removing_email_text', 10, 3 );
function customizing_checkout_text( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain )
{
    if ( 'Pay wish cash upon arriving to destination.' == $untranslated_text ) {
        $translated_text = __( '', $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).

You can also replace the text by something else.

Comment: Sorry but I can't get this to work. Even with changing the function name to removing_email_text it still doesn't change anything. Please advise.

Comment: @JackRobson Cool finally it's working with the the answer update…

Comment: I couldn't get the gettext filter to work but removing the text from inside the WooCommerce settings worked great. Thanks for your help.


Shame about the gettext filter, I have to replace all the instances of order with the word booking now and it's proving troublesome to locate them all. Got any tips?